# Increment Alphabet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to show alphabet like this in Javascript;

A,B,C,D....ZX,ZY,ZZ

I tried like this;

```
var cols[A, B, C, D...Z];

cols.join(',');

for (var i = cols[0]; i < cols.length; i++) {
    for(var j = cols[0]; j < cols.length; j++) {
        var k = 'i' + 'j';
    }
}

document.write(<span> + cols.join + </span>);
```

Could you tell me how to write source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty easy to accomplish with 2 arrays, with one containing an extra blank entry

```js
var char1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']; // shortened for demo - make a..z
var char2 = ['','A','B','C','D','E','F']; // shortened for demo, make a..z

var result = [];
for(var i=0;i<char2.length;i++)
{   
   for(var j=0;j<char1.length;j++)
   {
      result.push(char2[i] + char1[j])
   }
}

for(var x=0;x<result.length;x++)
{
    document.write(result[x] + " ")
}
```

As was noted in comments, making an array of characters is much easier in practice using

```
var char1 = 'ABCDEF'.split('');
```

Comment: It's easier to write "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("") than the array version in my opinion.

Comment: @Bálint I totally agree. However I wanted to make it clear I was using an array, to help what looked like a fairly inexperienced dev.

Comment: Thank a lot! You've been very helpful.

Comment: I just said you could mention it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see.

Comment: This works but disappointed at javascript. Java has more convenient `'A' + 2 = 'C'` for the rescue